# Can I use the second choice in the boot sequence by disabling the hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, bios, password-protection

I was advised to transfer this question from Stack Overflow to this forum.

I bought a used acer laptop to install ubuntu on. And I forgot to check if the bios was protected by a password. It is. (an old story heard many times, I'm sure)

So I need it to boot from the linux image on a usb drive, or I could make a cd if I could get it to boot from that.

It now boots from the hard drive.

If I disable the hard drive somehow, would it choose the second choice, whatever that is, and boot from that?

Comment: Please don't add line breaks manually. Computers can do that themselves and they do it better than us. Regarding your issue, it's important how you want to "disable hard drive *somehow*". I can't think of any other way than removing it physically.

Comment: I'm wondering if the system cannot boot from the first choice on the boot sequence list, will it try to boot from the second on the list?

Comment: That's the point of having boot sequence list. Devices are probed one by one until a bootable one is found.

Comment: Then, if I disable the hard drive, the computer should boot to ubuntu on the usb stick! right?

Comment: Unless the BIOS password prevents booting from other devices or hard drive is the only boot sequence item configured in BIOS. The real problem here is that your BIOS is password-locked.

Comment: ok. I'll try it and post the result. Thank you for the information.